# Сохранить размер и позицию элемента при изменении родительского элемента в HTML через Javascript

Tags: javascript, html

У меня есть элемент в ячейке таблицы, у него в стиле указано `width: 100%; height: 100%`, я вытаскиваю элемент из таблицы и перемещаю его в `body`. После этого меняю стиль элемента на `position: fixed;`, мне надо, чтобы теперь элемент находился в том же месте на странице и был того же размера.
`element.getBoundingClientRect()` не подходит, он выдает завышенные размеры

Comment: Перед тем как задать `position: fixed` нужно определить ширину и высоту в пикселях, а также положение элемента относительно окна браузера. После позиционирования  - применить все это к элементу

Comment: @Дмытрык Если вы имеете в виду `element.getBoundingClientRect()`, то это не подходит, он выдает завышенные значения (Отображается высотой в 16px, а element.getBoundingClientRect().height===21)

Comment: значит метод возвращает высоту согласно спецификации CSS: "Согласно спецификации CSS ширина блока складывается из ширины содержимого (width), значений margin, padding и border. Аналогично обстоит и с высотой блока. "